# CMake execution order - first build shared library then look for it from another project

Tags: cmake

I have the following `cmake` setup:

```
colorizer_root
    |
    |-------colorizer_lib
    |-------colorizer_template_project
```

The **colorizer_root** contains the top level CMakeLists.txt which is invoked when running `cmake`:

*colorizer_root* **CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(colorizer_root)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

add_subdirectory(colorizer_lib)
add_subdirectory(colorizer_template_project)
```

As you can see it contains 2 subdirectories each a project on its own. Basically what the **colorizer_lib** does is create a shared library named **libcolorize.so** (no executables here!), which then is to be used by the other project **colorizer_template_project** (the executable is created in this project). Here are the two CMakeLists.txt files for their respective projects:

*colorizer_lib* **CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(colorizer_lib)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=gnu++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
include_directories(. INCLUDES)
add_library(colorizer SHARED colorizer.cpp)
```

*colorizer_template_project* **CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(colorizer_template_project)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_library(COLORIZER_LIB colorizer
                    PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/colorizer_lib
)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${COLORIZER_LIB})
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how the whole lookup thing works. The problem here is that when I run the top level CMakeLists.txt it goes through both (obviously) but during processing the **colorizer_template_project** it breaks with a complaint:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
COLORIZER_LIB
    linked by target "colorizer_template_project" in directory /home/USER/Programming/C_Cpp/colorizer/colorizer_template_project
```

This is an expected behaviour since **libcolorizer.so** cannot be present at the time of running `cmake` because it is created after `make` has been invoked.

How do I tell `cmake` to first process the first project (including the build step!) and then go to the next one? I know that this works if I add an executable to the project that creates the library and then directly link it to the binary but in this case I want separate projects for the library and the executable that is using it.

PS: I haven't given any details about the sources because they are not important here. It is - I believe - a general question, which is not specific to whether I'm using C, C++ or something similar.

Comment: `colorizer` target is actually accessible for **colorizer_template_project**, so you can directly link with it.

Comment: It works. But why? Is is because of the top level project?

Comment: `project` command just adds definition of serveral variables. It doesn't break visibility rules of other targets and variables.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please write your first comment as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project` command doesn't make subprojects independent, so `colorizer` target is actually accessible for **colorizer_template_project**, and you can directly link with it:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} colorizer)
```